# UISearchBar dismiss animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a UITableViewController with a SearchBar and search display controller:

[image]

Everything is by default. The navigation bar is translucent. When you click on the search bar the navigation bar slides up. Now when you dismiss the search it slides back in, which creates a white gap between search and navigation bar:

[image]

Any ideas what causes this and how to fix it? I am using swift, iOS8.1 and xcode6.1

---

The only thing I can do is setting the view background of the table view to blue. But this has the negative side effect that everything will be blue when table view is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the code you posted on GitHub](http://github.com/ArtworkAD/ios_animation_gap) I could find a way to avoid the gap, obviously a matter of animation timing.

In your FirstTableViewController.swift you need to register as a delegate of UISearchBar, then trigger yourself the appearing of the navigationBar the earlier possible when the searchBar dismisses (as soon as the text editing ends) with the delegate method searchBarTextDidEndEditing:

Here is your final swift file with 2 additions : the *UISearchBarDelegate* on line 3, and the function *searchBarTextDidEndEditing* at the end :

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var entries: NSArray = ["Foo", "Bar"];

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.entries.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = entries[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: nil)
    }

    // Fix searchbar disappear bug

    func searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch(controller: UISearchDisplayController) {
        self.tableView.insertSubview(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar, aboveSubview: self.tableView)
    }


    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }


}
```

EDIT - by adjusting the proper layout options in IB, both viewcontrollers work.

First : The 3 checked options for the TableViews are in Drawing: Opaque + Clears Graphics Context + Autoresize Subviews

Second : For the ViewController itself the Extended Edges checked options are: Under Bottom Bars + Under Opaque Bars

And third : the code above about UISearchBar Delegation...

Comment: Did you test this? I did right now and it is not working, the animation is strange.

Comment: I tested this by adding those few things into your demo project : I could see the _red_ background upon dismissal, but with those additions I do not see anymore any red = no gap... (?) - I could send you the modified project (dunno how...)

Comment: But what about the second view (SecondViewController)? I now that the First works, but the second does not work. Did you check this?

Comment: Ok I could achieve it : [please find here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/375309/ios_animation_gap-master.zip) the modified version of your project, the searchBar dismisses without gap and/or red appearing...

Comment: Ok just added some more info in my answer - I think that's pretty much all what I changed

Comment: i send you the right code again. the workaround of poozolax works, but it is not necessary. there is no bug in apple code which should be masked.

Answer (score 3):

Try placing your UISearchBar outside the Table View and not as a subview of it. It might be a small design change but the animations are much better.

Comment: This is actually a nice solution but the storyboard does not allow dragging the searchbar above the table view.

Comment: @artworkadシ Most of the time, because of certain design elements, I use a plain UIViewController and drag the UITableView onto it, and hook up the delegate/datasource manually. In this case you'll also have to hook up the Search Display Controllers. This way you can customise the view more than using a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "white gap" is the table view controller's background color.  I suppose you could change the table view controller's background color to match the search bar or the navigation bar, but then the entire table view controller will also be that color.

Comment: +1 your right, when I change the table background to blue the gap is not visible. However I need the table background to be white...

Comment: Why not replace your UITableViewController with a UIViewController. Set the background of the contentView to blue. Then add a UITableView with constraints to the top layout guide. This will let you have a blue background under the navigation bar but also let you have a table with a white background.

Answer (score 2):

Change your search bar to gray color(i.e.,your background color).It may help you

Answer (score 2):

the white color there is the background color of your navigation controller

1) in storyboard assign the class of your navigation controller and set its background color to whatever you want ... like in my example i did in viewDidLoad().

2) set backgroundColor of your table view. by default it will be the same as underlying nav controller background (doing it in storyboard is OK)

```
class NavControllerViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

if you want the same color as your nav bar has

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view.backgroundColor = navigationBar.tintColor
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working. The only way I can make the space blue is by making the whole table background blue.

Comment: i checked it on my computer, it works! it runs now, i have red gap, blue navbar and yellow empty table. did you set both colors? you have to set view.backgroundColor in your nav controller (programmatically only) and also backgroundColor of your table. if you want, i can share small project with you

Comment: Please Share it, via github for example

Comment: Your solution worked for me, however only for the first view. If you navigation from on table view to another, it does not work for the second view. I offer another 200rep bounty on this question. Check out my version of your code: https://github.com/ArtworkAD/ios_animation_gap it works for the first table view, but not for the second.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

class NavControllerViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.backgroundColor = view.tintColor
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}


class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var entries: NSArray = ["Foo", "Bar"];

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.entries.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = entries[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: nil)
    }

}

class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var entries: NSArray = ["Foo", "Bar"]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.entries.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = entries[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }

}
```

there is NOT necessary to do any special trick. as i wrote in my first answer, the white gap is just the background color of main view of NavigationController.

this code works for me, i set now tintColor and backgroundColor to red, to show you, what happens behind ...

Answer (score 1):

The statusBar color is caused by **extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars** property.
It is set as Yes in default.Set it to No, then the status bar will always have the same color.

Hopes it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question i've created similar sample demo and came to a concluding that you are getting white space between navigation bar and search bar is because you have set search Bar Controller instead of search Bar.

I've done some more digging and learned that it is a **default behaviour of searchbar**.

While using search Bar Controller outside table view will also show space between navigation bar and search bar.

Instead of using UISearchBarController you need to use UISearch Bar on UIView outside UItableView.

You can show and hide navigation bar in similar way with Search Bar in following method using animation to hide and show navigation bar.

### **EDIT:**

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
        }, completion: { value in
            //comment below lines is you want smooth animation.
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.alpha = 0
    })
    return true
}
```

---

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
           // Uncomment below line for smooth animation effect.
           // self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = false
        }, completion: { finished in
            //comment below lines is you want smooth animation.
            self.navigationController!.navigationBar.alpha = 1
            self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = false
    })
}
```

Now you no need to set background color as navigation bar color it wall not have smooth animation as before when **searchBarCancelButtonClicked**.

But this will not have the smooth animation as before. 
So you can just set that background color as navigation bar color.

Hope this might Solve your problem.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ArtworkAD/ios_animation_gap I created it to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Hi, I've checked the demo you have created. Just as i expected you have use search Bar Controller and is set inside tableView. I've added the demo you can check it out. All you needed is to use searchBar instead of searchBarController. Use search bar and your issue will be solved.  https://github.com/iOSDevDK/SFSearchBarAnswer.git

Comment: It's not working, make your navigation bar e.g. blue and you see it.

Comment: Ya i've check it by changing the navigation color. It seemed after setting background color same as navigation color it solves the problem.